# How to change permission of django project?

Tags: django, python-3.x, permissions

I have created my project in centOS 7 using root.Each time when saving the project after changes its asking the password.How do I change the permissions of the whole project now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make everything writable by anyone run this in directory with your django project:

```
chmod -R 0777 ./
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to keep it owned by root? I'd suggest to change the owner to whatever services should use the project.

```
chown -R <some-user> /path/to/project # user may be www-data
chmod -R 755 /path/to/project
```